# Magento tax doesnt get calculated based on [subtotal] minus [discount] but just [subtotal]

Tags: magento-1.7, tax, coupon

I've currently setup a coupon code that when entered gives 10% on everything in the shopping cart.

This works fine, **my issue though is that Tax is calculated wrong**.
Currently tax is calculated purely based on the  [subtotal]

If discount is applied I need tax to be calculated based on:
[subtotal] - [discount] = [amount_to_base_tax_calculation_on] * [tax_rate] = Correct tax

Is there any settings / options ive missed to make the checkout page do this?

Comment: what settings do you have for tax setup?

Comment: Totally missed the tax options in configuration. It was truly easy to edit. Posted the "solution" below

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Go to System > Configuration > Sales > Tax
"Apply Customer Tax" set to: "After Discount"